# Updatable chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-manipulation, chord-diagram

I am working on a D3 chord diagram and want to have an update function.

This is the code I have at the moment

```
// Genres, check de readme daar staat visueel hoe je dit uitleest. 
var data = [
  [9962, 1196, 94, 93, 18],
  [1196, 9102, 11, 343, 169],
  [94, 11, 7143, 138, 32],
  [93, 343, 138, 6440, 75],
  [18, 169, 32, 75, 4886]
]

var genres = ["Psychologischverhaal", "Thriller", "Detective", "Romantischverhaal", "Sciencefiction"]

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * 0.5 - 40,
    innerRadius = outerRadius - 30;

// Zet getallen naar 1K ipv 1000
var formatValue = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e3);

var chord = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(0.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.ascending);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#ed0b0b", "#03aa24", "#f2ae04", "#1f03f1", "#e1ed04"]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .datum(chord(data));

var group = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "groups")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
  .enter().append("g");

group.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.index)).darker(); })
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + d.index; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1)) 
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));

group.append("title").text(function(d) {
        return groupTip(d);
});

group.append("text")
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("dy", 15)
      .append("textPath")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#group" + d.index; })
        .text(function(chords, i){return genres[i];})
        .style("fill", "black");

var groupTick = group.selectAll(".group-tick")
  .data(function(d) { return groupTicks(d, 1e3); })
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-tick")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ") translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)"; });

groupTick.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 1)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 5)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", "#000")

groupTick
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value % 1e3 === 0; })
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180) translate(-16)" : null; })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return formatValue(d.value); });

var ribbons = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "ribbons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", ribbon)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })

ribbons.append("title").
    text(function(d){return chordTip(d);});


// Returns an array of tick angles and values for a given group and step.
function groupTicks(d, step) {
  var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, step).map(function(value) {
    return {value: value, angle: value * k + d.startAngle};
  });
}

function fade(opacity) {
  return function(d, i) {
    ribbons
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i;
        })
      .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}

function chordTip(d){
  var j = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e1)
     return "Aantal boeken met genres:\n"
        + genres[d.target.index] + " en " + genres[d.source.index] + ": " + j(d.source.value)
}

function groupTip(d) {
        var j = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e1)
        return "Totaal aantal boeken met het genre " + genres[d.index] + ":\n" + j(d.value)
}
```

and

```
<body>
<h1>Boeken met enkele & dubbele genres</h1>
<button id="doubleGenre">Alleen dubbele genres</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<svg width="960" height="900"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/index.js"></script>
```

This is the result what I have now :
[image]

I want to update the chord when a user clicks on the button *Alleen dubbele genres* so it becomes like this :

[image]

So I want to delete the chords to it self so the data looks like :

```
var data = [
  [1196, 94, 93, 18],
  [1196, 11, 343, 169],
  [94, 11, 138, 32],
  [93, 343, 138, 75],
  [18, 169, 32, 75]
]
```

And if a user clicks on the button *reset* I want to go back to the original view. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: write a function that has `data` as argument, start by removing the old chord chart `d3.select('svg').remove()` and then just draw a new one. in the click callback call this function with the correct data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the simplified version of your example with transitions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/q53412789

[image: Gif with animation]

If you want to remove chords to self, you should replace values on diagonal to zeros (not just delete them: matrix must remain square):

```
const data2 = [
  [0, 1196, 94, 93, 18],
  [1196, 0, 11, 343, 169],
  [94, 11, 0, 138, 32],
  [93, 343, 138, 0, 75],
  [18, 169, 32, 75, 0]
]
```

As @rioV8 suggested, the first step is to wrap code for drawing and updating the chart into a function (I've ommited code for ticks and labels for brevity, the principle is the same for them):

```
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

var ribbons = g.append("g");

function update(data) {
  const chords = chord(data);

  const ribbonsUpdate = ribbons.selectAll("path")
    .data(chords, ({source, target}) => source.index + '-' + target.index)

  const duration = 3000;

  ribbonsUpdate
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", ribbon)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })

  ribbonsUpdate
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("opacity", 0)
      .attr("d", ribbon)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('opacity', 1)

  ribbonsUpdate
    .exit()
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .remove();
}

update(data1);
```

I've replaced combination of `.datum(val)` and `.data(fun)` in your code to single `.data(vals)`. It is not required, but my opinion is that the latter is more common in d3 community.

The second argument to `.data` is the key function. It ensures, that during transition each path maps to itself in the new data (the number of chords is not equal: we removed chords to itself).

If you do not need animated transitions, the code is even simplier:

```
function simpleUpdate(data) {
  const chords = chord(data);

  const ribbonsUpdate = ribbons.selectAll("path")
    .data(chords, ({source, target}) => source.index + '-' + target.index)

  ribbonsUpdate
    .enter().append("path")
    .merge(ribbonsUpdate)
      .attr("d", ribbon)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); })

  ribbonsUpdate.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your help and example. Unfortunately I am still a beginner with D3 and the chord diagram is hard to make. I am trying to understand what I do. I tried to add the ticks and labels to the function update but it doesn't work at all. If you want to take a look this is what I have now : https://stackblitz.com/edit/q53412789-rp3k9p :(

Comment: Update as you can see in the stackblitz, I got labels working, but they don't update when I click on the button. I also can't get fixed the groupticks.

Comment: I've modified your code, so labels are animated properly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/q53412789-ajzz5d?file=index.js. There were several corrections: 1. `var group` should be declared outside `update`, 2. `var groupUpdate` should take value inside `.data(`, not function.  3. When you `.append()` after `.enter()`, you should add single element. If you have two elements (`path` and `text`), they must be inside group.